# Calculating area of overlap between two polygons in separate layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, overlay

I have 2 layers with 1-1 polygon. The polygons are overlapping.

How do I calculate the area of the overlap using QGIS?

[image: Made an example, they are transparent.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an "Intersection".

Vector> Geoprocessing Tools> Intersection

Then identify the resulting layer, and it will have an area in the (Derived) stats.